# Inductively. If a, b, c ≥ 1, prove that 4(abc + 1) ≥ (1 + a) (1 + b) (1 + c)

Tags: induction

Any idea to prove this problem by induction?. If $$a, b, c ≥ 1,$$ prove that $$4(abc + 1) ≥ (1 + a) (1 + b) (1 + c)$$(Suggestion- Rencia: Prove, more generally, that $${{{2^n}^-}^1} (a_1a_2\cdots a_n+1) ≥ (1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdots(1+a_n).)$$

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

- base case $n=1 \implies (a_1+1)\ge (a_1+1)$
- inducion step, we assume true ${2^{n-1}} (a_1a_2...a_n+1) \ge (1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)$ and we need to prove that ${2^{n}}  (a_1a_2...a_{n+1}+1) \ge (1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_{n+1})$, then consider

$${2^{n}}  (a_1a_2...a_{n+1}+1)=2\cdot2^{n-1}a_1a_2...a_{n+1}+2^n\stackrel{Ind. Hyp.}\ge 2\left((1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)-2^{n-1}\right)a_{n+1}+2^n=(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)\cdot 2a_{n+1}-2^na_{n+1}+2^n\stackrel{?}\ge (1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_{n+1})$$

then to complete the proof we need to check the following

$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)\cdot 2a_{n+1}-2^na_{n+1}+2^n\stackrel{?}\ge (1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_{n+1})$$